# How do I write a Controller class in Spring Boot for many Databases?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have multiple databases (MySQL and a 4 NoSQL databases). The service classes all implement a CustomerServiceClass for CRUD-operations.
This is how my Controller Class looks:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/customer")
public class CustomerController {

@Autowired
CustomerService customerService;

public CustomerController(CustomerService customerService) { this.customerService = customerService;}

@RequestMapping(value = "/{Id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Customer> create(@RequestBody CustomerData customerData) {
    customerService.create(customerData);
    return new ResponseEntity<Customer>(customerData, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/{Id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<Customer> read(@PathVariable("Id") String Id){
    Customer customer = (Customer)customerService.read(Id);
    if (customer == null){
        return new ResponseEntity<Customer>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<Customer>(customer, HttpStatus.OK);

}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Customer> retrieveCustomers(){
    return customerService.retrieveAllCustomers();
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/{Id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public ResponseEntity<Customer> update(@PathVariable("Id") String Id,    @RequestBody CustomerData customerData) {

    Customer currentCustomer = (Customer)customerService.read(Id);
    if(currentCustomer == null){
        return new ResponseEntity<Customer>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
    currentCustomer.setName(customerData.getName());
    currentCustomer.setDistrict(customerData.getDistrict());
    currentCustomer.setDate(customerData.getDate());

    customerService.create(currentCustomer);
    return new ResponseEntity<Customer>(currentCustomer, HttpStatus.OK);

}

@RequestMapping(value = "/{Id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
public ResponseEntity<Void> delete(@PathVariable String Id){
    Customer customer = (Customer)customerService.read(Id);
    if (customer==null){
        return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }else {
        customerService.delete(Id);
        return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.GONE);
    }
  }}
```

This is how the CustomerService interface looks:

```
@Component
public interface CustomerService<E>{

E create(Customer customer);

E read(String id);

List<E> retrieveAllCustomers();

E update(String Id, Customer customer);

//List<Order> retrieveAllOrders(String customerId);

void delete(String id);

void deleteAll();}
```

This for example is my MySQL-CustomerService class:

```
@Service("myCustomerService")
@Qualifier("myCustomerService")
@Profile(Profiles.MYSQL)
public class MyCustomerService implements CustomerService{

@Autowired
private MyCustomerRepository customerRepository;

@Override
public Customer create(Customer customer) {
    MyCustomer myCustomer = new MyCustomer(customer);
    customerRepository.save(myCustomer);
    return myCustomer;
}

@Override
public Customer read(String id) { return customerRepository.findOne(id); }

@Override
public List<MyCustomer> retrieveAllCustomers() { return customerRepository.findAll(); }

@Override
public Customer update(String id, Customer customerData) {
    MyCustomer customer = customerRepository.findOne(id);
    customer.copy(customerData);
    customerRepository.save(customer);
    return customer;
}


@Override
public void delete(String id) { customerRepository.delete(id); }

@Override
public void deleteAll() { customerRepository.deleteAll(); }}
```

I do the same for the NoSQL classes.

This is the error message I get and I have tried everything to fix it (adding qualifier, etc.):

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'customerController' defined in file [/demo/controller/CustomerController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'demo.service.CustomerService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

UPDATE: 
This is my yml file for the properties:

```
spring:
datasource:
url: jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb
username: root
driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
data:
mongodb:
  uri: mongodb://localhost:27017/MongoTest
cassandra:
  keyspace-name: db_keyspace
  contact-points: localhost
  port: 9042
  schema-action: create_if_not_exists
neo4j:
  uri: bolt://localhost:7474
  username: neo4j
  password: root

jpa:
  properties:
  hibernate.show_sql: true
  hibernate.use_sql_comments: true
  hibernate.format_sql: true
  hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

mvc:
view:
  prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp
  suffix: .jsp

logging:
file: logback-spring.xml
level: DEBUG
```

Adding @Primary to one of the Database-Service classes solves the problem. But I need to retrieve data from ALL classes of different databases without choosing one particularly.

Thanks in advance for any kind of help!

Comment: Have you tried removing the ` @Qualifier` and/or the `@Profile` annotations at the ` MyCustomerService` class?

Comment: Update a configuration where your bean is defined.

Comment: I updated my answer and removed the qualifier annotation...still the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you do not activate the profile for the database you want to use when starting your Spring app.

If you use `@Profile(Profiles.WHATEVER)` on your CustomerServices, then you need to active one of the profiles when running your application.

You can do that using the application properties in the .yml-file (set spring.profiles.active=WHATEVER), the run configuration in the Spring Tool Suite (it has a separate field to enter profiles), or a command line argument

`-Dspring.profiles.active="WHATEVER"`.

The command line argument can also be added to the VM arguments in a Eclipse Run Configuration for a Java application (if you don't use Spring Tool Suite)

For testing, take a look at the `@ActiveProfiles` annotation (or define active profiles in a special properties file for testing).

`@Primary` also activates a profile: it tells Spring which CustomerService to use when you have not selected a profile through other means, or when you have activated several profiles that include CustomerServices (if one of them has a @Primary annotation, it will get selected; otherwise you get an exception telling you that Spring has found too many CustomerServices).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should remove CustomService customerService from the CustomerController Constructor.
You don't need to set the CustomerService in the constructor, because it will automatically gets injected in the CustomerServiceField via the @Autowired Annotation.

```
@Autowired
CustomerService customerService;

public CustomerController() 
{
}
```

If you want to use constructor injection (Good for tests), you can use it like this:

```
CustomerService customerService;

@Autowired
public CustomerController(CustomerService customerService) 
{
    this.customerService = customerService;
}
```